# Dynamically adding an angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have timer that periodically loads data from server. These data should be represented in set of form on the same page.
 User can add new form, and when form adding, query to server is changed and starts loading data for new form too. Also these forms should be draggabe and resizable.

I try to make this with ng-repeat but this break my draggable  and resizable because of reloading of divs ( coordinates of my draggable view resets after every loading data from the server).

Part of html:

```
<div     ng-repeat="dev in devices" style="border:1px solid grey;">
    <div  draggable_  style="width:400px" class="ui-widget-content" ng-include=  "'partials/' + dev.type + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
diagApp.controller('diagCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout','$compile',
    function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile) {
        var cmds = [];
        $scope.devices = [];
        var onTimer = function() {
           var path = location.href;
           path = path.replace(/diagpro.*$/, 'diagpro/my1_json.php')
           var onSucc = function(data) {
               for (var t in data) {
               var tp = data[t].cmd;
               $scope.devices[tp] = data[t];
           }
           $scope.devices = data;     
        }
        $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: path,
           data: cmds.join(' '),
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},

        }).success(onSucc);      

       $timeout(onTimer, 1000);

 }]);
```

draggable directive:

```
diagApp.directive('draggable_', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            callback: '&onDrag'
        },
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
           elem.draggable();
           elem.on('dragstop', function (evt, ui) {
              if (scope.callback) { scope.callback(); }
           });
       }
   };
});
```

Thus the problem coming with dynamically adding new instance of different view templates. How could I make this with angularjs?

Comment: How are you binding your draggable?

Comment: This isn't exactly the angular way, but if you are using jQuery and set your binding to bind a child selector via the parent (ie: `$('#parent').on('click', '.children', function(e){/**/});`, no matter how many child nodes are added/removed, your draggable binding would still work. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/RqF9f/) an example of binding like that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. By"break my draggable" I mean that coordinates of my draggable view resets after every loading data from the server

Comment: Any luck with the answer?